# Both my tests are failing even though they are in contrast (expect(...).to and expect(...).not_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm very new to rspec testing. I've tried the following test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "CategoriesController" do

  describe "#index" do

    context "when signed in" do

      it "should have the content 'Sign in'" do
        visit categories_path
        expect(page).to have_content('Sign in')
      end
    end

    context "when signed in" do

      it "should not have the content 'Sign in'" do
        visit categories_path
        expect(page).not_to have_content('Sign in')
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Now, I will add some authentication but for not I just want one test to pass and the other to fail. At the moment both are failing, even though they are identical other than .to and .not_to

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the failure message?

Comment: AFAIK the `expect` API is `.to_not` and _not_ `.not_to`...

Answer (score 1):

Your test looks like it ought to be in a Capybara feature spec, where the test imitates how a user interacts with a browser.  But the `describe "CategoriesController" do` makes it look like you actually wrote a controller spec.

Try rewriting as such, after adding [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to your Gemfile.

```
# in spec/features/sessions_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Sessions" do
  scenario "when not signed in" do
    visit categories_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Sign in')
  end

  scenario "when signed in" do
    visit categories_path
    expect(page).not_to have_content('Sign in')
  end
end
```

To debug the test once you have made it a feature spec, you can also add `save_and_open_page` like this:

```
  scenario "when signed in" do
    visit categories_path
    save_and_open_page
    expect(page).not_to have_content('Sign in')
  end
```

Comment: I see. I'm aware of Capybara but not familiar yet with the methods to understand when it's being relied upon. Should the test not trigger an error where a Gem is missing rather than running but failing? I'm unsure how, when running specs written by others, to distinguish between various Gems (at this stage anyway)

Comment: In general, in a controller spec, Capybara will never be relied on. In a feature spec, it will always be relied on.  Did the revisions I suggested (that is, move the spec from being a controller spec to being a feature spec) work?

Comment: Yes. Actually it told me that save_and_open_page requires the launchy gem though too which I added to my Gemfile. After bundle install everything worked well, save_and_open_page will really come in handy I think. Thanks